# Fast algorithm for evenly distributing points inside a closed curve with non-overlapping boundaries

Tags: algorithm, optimization, distance

The problem is that I need to allocate some people in an office room with arbitrary shape. The requirement of each person is the same: far away from the office wall and other people as much as possible.

Consider the office room as a blank image. So allocating people is like distributing points on the image.

The algorithm I figured out is slow:

```
for each people
  do distance transform of the image
  find a point that has the largest distance value
  place a people here
  mark the pixel where the people is as False in the image
```

The algorithm does distance transform several times and place people iteratively.

The algorithm becomes really slow when there are lots of people, say 500 since the iterative use of distance transform. I'm wondering if there're better algorithm or any idea I can optimize the current algorithm? Thanks

Comment: So, you want to evenly distribute points inside a closed curve with non-overlapping boundaries, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: A simple solution is just run a kmeans clustering then use the cluster center!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a centroidal Voronoi tesselation [1,2].
The algorithm works as follows:

```
(1) distribute the points randomly in the office
(2) Repeat until you are satisfied:
  (2.1) compute the Voronoi diagram (see [3]) of the points
  (2.2) compute the barycenter of the Voronoi cell of each point
  (2.3) move each point to the barycenter of its Voronoi cell
```

There is an implementation in the GEOGRAM library that I am developping [4]. See also the CGAL library developped by friends of mine[5].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

[4] http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html

[5] http://www.cgal.org

Comment: @hatchet good point, I have added the reference you suggested, thanks.